# mysql persistent connection

Tags: mysql

How to close a mysql  persistent connection?

Comment: You seem to have omitted something...

Comment: Any reason to close **persistent** connection? You either need non-persistent connection or non-closable persistent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language are you using?  Php?  Persistent connects will timeout if on an non-interactive session based on the wait_timeout variable in my.cnf.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

If you are using PHP (just guessing here) take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

There are some interesting discussions on the use of persistent connections - http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/12/are-php-persistent-connections-evil/

Answer (score 1):

You can't, simply wait for database server restart to reset all connection or maximum allow connection exceeded

There is no reason to issue persistent connection as it just hold the connection resource without release, another word, if your site having lots of traffic, soon you will get a connection error message.

And there is no reason to use mysql related function, switch to mysqli or pdo.